# null exeption error when apply List<Predicate<T>> to IQueryable list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have code like below, in this code if `FirstName` (that comes from view) has data, its add a condition to `criteria` list:

```
var criteria = new List<Predicate<ContactItem>>();
if (!IsNullOrEmpty(modelPage.FirstName))
{
    criteria.Add(o => o.FirstName.Contains(modelPage.FirstName));
}

list = _contactRepository.Query().Where(c => criteria.All(pred => pred(c)));
```

it's Ok, But in the code below, when the `Count()` run, I got null exception error from `modelPage.FirstName` ...!

```
var totalRecords = list.Count();
```

Comment: So `modelPage` is `null`? I'm not clear on what the question is here.

Comment: @CalC I want to create a list of filters, and then use that list for where condition.